# Changing the Text Color of a NSTokenField

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Need your help.
I want to change the text color of a NSTokenfield. Is it possible?
Googled for the same and couldnt find any usable links.
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NSTokenField super class is NSTextField. So you can use setTextColor.
eg :

```
NSTokenField *field = [[NSTokenField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[field setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
```

Please refer this for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/setTextColor:

Comment: Thank you sheen. This works fine if we create a new token field (Typing and Pressing enter)

This is not working if do this
[self.tokenFieldName setObjectValue:An Array];
Now if i try to change the colours in shouldAddobject,DispalayStringForRepObject(Delegate methods) it is not working Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure on this , may you can try setNeedsDisplay after setting color. If its not working you can with setAttributedStringValue.